# How to loop through unity gameobjects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make a script that loops through all game objects with the tag, `Enemy`
I modified a code snippet from [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/50208/loop-through-all-objects-with-same-tag.html), and ended up with 2 errors.

---

```
Cannot Implicitly convert 'Unity.GameObject[]' to 'Unity.GameObject'
```

and

```
Error   CS1579  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'GameObject' because 'GameObject' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'
```

If anyone could tell me why this is happening or a solution to this I would be very grateful, thanks in advance!
*Here is my code:*

```
void FixedUpdate()

{
    GameObject objects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");
    var objectCount = objects.Length;
    foreach (var obj in objects)
    {
        // Move the players accordingly
        //var rb = 
        Vector2 direction = (player.position - transform.position).normalized;
        obj.rigidbody.velocity = direction * moveSpeed;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`FindGameObjectsWithTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) as the name hints returns a `GameObject[]`.

In order tog et the attached `Rigidbody2D` use [`GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html)

It should be either `GameObject[]` or simply `var`

```
/*GameObject[]*/ var objects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");
var objectCount = objects.Length;
foreach (var obj in objects)
{
    // Move the players accordingly
    var rb = obj.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>()
    Vector2 direction = (player.position - transform.position).normalized;
    rb.velocity = direction * moveSpeed;
}
```

The second one was just a follow up error since you declared `objects` as a `GameObject` which indeed as the error says has no `GetEnumerator` implementation.

---

In general it is not the best thing to use `FindObjectsWithTag` repeatedly. I would rather use a pattern with a `static` list of all existing instances like

```
// Put this component on your enemy prefabs / objects
public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour
{
    // every instance registers to and removes itself from here
    private static readonly HashSet<EnemyController> _instances = new HashSet<EnemyController>();
    
    // Readonly property, I would return a new HashSet so nobody on the outside can alter the content
    public static HashSet<EnemyController> Instances => new HashSet<EnemyController>(_instances);

    // If possible already drag the Rigidbody into this slot via the Inspector!
    [SerializedField] private Rigidbody2D rb;

    // public read-only access
    public Rigidbody2D Rb => rb;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!rb) rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        _instances.Add(this);
    }


    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        _instances.Remove(this);
    }
}
```

and then use

```
var enemies = EnemyControler.Instances;
foreach (var enemy in enemies)
{
    // Move the players accordingly
    Vector2 direction = (player.position - transform.position).normalized;
    enemy.Rb.velocity = direction * moveSpeed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `GameObject` type declaration to `var`

Or change it to `GameObject[]` since `FindGameObjectsWithTag` returns an array of `GameObject`

Also I wouldnt use `FindGameObjectsWithTag` its slow. More so in a update method

Comment: I changed GameObject to GameObject[] but I still can't figure out how to access the rigid body for that specific object.

Comment: You need to get it using GetComponent but it's slow too, create a domain specific type that holds enemy logic

Answer (score 1):

First off, change `GameObject` to `GameObject[]` because `FindGameObjectsWithTag` returns a `GameObject` array. Be careful not to confuse it with `FindGameObjectWithTag` without the s which returns a single `GameObject`

Secondly, I think it would be best to have a separate `Enemy` script or something like that and assign them to each enemy rather than using `FindGameObjectsWithTag` which is very slow.